# Electric furnace doesn't perform a cool down stage

Tags: furnace

When my electric furnace shuts down the fan also shuts down at the exact same time. I was told that it should run for a bit afterward to cool off the coils. Doing some research it looks like this is part of most, if not all furnaces. Is there setting that can be done to troubleshoot/resolve this? Possibly an adjustment somewhere?

Furnace is Central Electric, Model EB23B

Answer (score 1):

Gas and oil furnaces heat a heat exchanger so they have to run for quite awhile after the burner shuts off to cool down.
Electric furnaces don't have that issue since there is no heat exchanger.
If the air is still hot when it shuts off, the sequencer needs checked.
If the air is warm, it's normal.

Answer (score 0):

Looking up eb23b I came up with a Coleman unit even using central electric so it may be the same unit. From the wiring parts list I only see 1 part. Item number 20 sequencer part number 01-0843. This may be the off delay timer I would look at that or the fan relay itself to see if it has electronics for an adjustable delay off. Item 12 is the fan relay part# PR380.  In the layout the sequencer is above the coil racks to the left of the contactor the relay is to the left of the sequencer above the transformer.

Comment: Is there a place online I can look that these diagrams, or even a way to order a book on this unit?

Comment: Also, if there's no adjustments, does that mean that one of those parts is malfunctioning and should be replaced?

Comment: See the OWNER_MANUAL and INSTALLATION_GUIDE tabs. https://www.searspartsdirect.com/partsdirect/user-manuals/EB23B-Coleman-evcon-ind-Parts-Furnace-Parts-manual

Comment: @KellyElton - in general, a Google search for "Manual <brand> <model number>" will get what you need. Be careful, though, sometimes, the results will be for "<brand> <very similar model number>" and that can be confusing.